# Accerder a datos de un Array de Objetos y mostrar solo items

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, jsonobject, jsonarray

tengo un array de objetos el cual lo obtengo mediante una peticion API en cual es un array de objetos mi duda es como podria iterrrar en el array ya que no logro acceder al dato product

```
axios.get("api/admin/order/list").then(response => { 

    const productOrders = orders.map(function(response.data.data) {
        return JSON.parse(order.detail);
    });
    const products = productOrders.map(function(prod){
        for(var i=0; i <= prod.length; i++){ //recorrer array de objetos
            for(var j=0; j<=prod[i].product.length; j++ ){//recorrer array de productos
                 return  prod[i][j].name;
            }
        }
    });
})
```

tengo el siguiente resultado json el cual es un array de objetos

```
[   
    {  
        "product":{"id":2,"name":"chilaquiles","price":168},
        "quantity":2,
        "subTotal":"336.00"
    },
    {
        "product":{"id":1,"name":"pasta","price":167},
        "quantity":1,
        "subTotal":"167.00"
    }
],
[
    {
        "product":{"id":3,"name":"TV SONY","description":"tv 35p","price":178},
        "quantity":1,
        "subTotal":"178.00"
    }
]
```

la vista que obtengo es la siguiente
[image: la vista que tengo es esta en donde muestra las ordenes pero el detalle en donde quiero reformatear a que me muestre solo el algunos parametros como nombre de productos, etc]

lo que deseo es mostrar los productos de una order en items para cada fila como la imagen que solo muestre el nombre aqui un ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es importante entender la forma en la que trabajan los métodos antes de usarlos. Te lo comento porque tienes un `map`, y dentro un `for` y dentro otro `for`, con lo cual la performance de aplicativo se te irá a las nubes cuando el responde la API te traiga miles de datos (estás iterando dentro de una iteración, la cual itera dentro de otro ciclo)

Lo que requieres se puede hacer con un simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) de la siguiente manera

```js
const data = [  
   {  
      "product":{"id":2,"name":"chilaquiles","price":168},
      "quantity":2,
      "subTotal":"336.00"
   },
   {
      "product":{"id":1,"name":"pasta","price":167},
      "quantity":1,
      "subTotal":"167.00"
   }
]

const products = data.map(({ product: { name }}) => ({ name }))

console.log(products)
```

Dentro de la función map, estoy *desglosando* - tiene un nombre que no recuerdo ahora :( - para obtener sólo el valor que necesito, que en tu caso sería la propiedad `name` del objeto `producto`.

Cualquier duda nos comentas :)

Comment: sintaxis de desestructuracion puede ser?

Comment: Ese mismo! Agradecido @ElFuturoLlego :D

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que obtengo los datos del API que un array de objetos y dentro de ese array hay otro de productos no se si sea la manera de correcta de hacerlo lo ordene la primera parte para que se entendiera y se vea el array de arrays

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "date": "10-12-2022",
        "user": "Mrs Wlas",
        "detail": "[
            {
                "product":
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"chilaquiles",
                        "description":"chilaquiles en salsa chipotle",
                        "price":168,
                        "image":"images/1.png"
                    },
                "quantity":2,
                "subTotal":"336.00"
            },
                "product":
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"pasta",
                        "description":"pasta de tarta",
                        "price":167,
                        "image":"images/4.png"
                    },
                "quantity":1,
                "subTotal":"167.00"
            }
        ]",
        "totalDetail": "503.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "date": "10-12-2022",
        "user": "Mrs Plex",
        "detail": "[{\"product\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"TV SONY\",\"description\":\"tv 35p\",\"price\":178,\"image\":\"images/tv.png\"},\"quantity\":2,\"subTotal\":\"356.00\"}]",
        "totalDetail": "356.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "date": "10-12-2022",
        "user": "Mijael Paredes",
        "detail": "[{\"product\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"TV SONY\",\"description\":\"tv 35p\",\"price\":178,\"image\":\"images/tv.png\"},\"quantity\":1,\"subTotal\":\"178.00\"},{\"product\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"chilaquiles de queso\",\"description\":\"chilaquiles en salsa chipotle\",\"price\":168,\"image\":\"images/1.png\"},\"quantity\":1,\"subTotal\":\"168.00\"},{\"product\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"pasta\",\"description\":\"pasta de tarta\",\"price\":167,\"image\":\"images/4.png\"},\"quantity\":1,\"subTotal\":\"167.00\"},{\"product\":{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"Coca cola\",\"description\":\"coca cola 178ml\",\"price\":68,\"image\":\"images/cocacola.png\"},\"quantity\":1,\"subTotal\":\"68.00\"}]",
        "totalDetail": "581.00"
    }
]
```

explicando un poco el `JSON` el artibuto Detail guarda los productos serializados que se hicieron en esa orden de compra asi como una carrito de compras donde dentro de ella hay otro array de objetos llamado `product` el cual hace referencia a los productos que se añadieron a esa orden `detail[{product:{..},quantity,subTotal},{product:{..}, quantity,subTotal}]` no se si seria la manera correcta con solo poner el `id_product` en ves de guardar todo el objeto producto al array de datos ejemplo `detail[{id_product,quantity,subTotal},{id_product,quantity,subTotal}]`
lo hice de esta manera para tener ya listos los datos de los productos y mostrarlos directamente

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición a la pregunta?